# I face this error;; AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'corroef'

Tags: python, correlation, feature-extraction, feature-selection, error-correction

I try to use correlation to extract features , but I faced this problem:
please help me, how I can fix it?

> AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'corroef'

This my code to correlate the features::

````
    cor_list = []
    feature_name = X_train[0]
    print(feature_name)
    #calculate the correlation with y for each feature
    for i in feature_name:
        cor = np.corroef(X_train[i], y_train)[0, 1]
        cor_list.append(cor)
     #replace NaN with 0
    cor_list = [0 if np.isnan(i) else i for i in cor_list]
    #feature_name
    cor_feature = X_train.iloc[:np.argsort(np.abs(cor_list))[-num_feats:]].columns.tolist()
    return cor_feature ```
````

Comment: By using `corrcoef` rather than `correof` ...

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelled corrcoef...
This is the syntax:

```
numpy.corrcoef(x, y=None, rowvar=True, bias=<no value>, ddof=<no value>, *, dtype=None)
```

Comment: This deserves to be a **comment** (and it already is) rather than an answer ...

Comment: I dont know how this works . but if that how that is, then understood !1

Comment: Thank  you I fix the misspellted, but appear another problem


In this line:
`cor = np.corrcoef(X_train[i], y_train)[0, 1]`
 IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: Looks like you are not properly indexing the numpy array. print out the values of the index and check if they are proper